# Install old version of symfony

Tags: symfony1, version

I install symfony through pear, it install latest version of symfony (symfony 1.4.20). But I want to install old version symfony 1.2.2. How can I change latest version to old version.

Answer (score 2):

You tell pear which version to install:

```
pear install symfony/symfony-1.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get whatever legacy version you want from http://symfony.com/legacy and replace the symfony code within the lib/vendor directory.